# changing the look of the radio button

Tags: javascript, css, radio-button

I am sure this question was asked before but I am looking for a very specific way to style a radio button.
Here is the [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/0ft019xj/101/) of what I currently have

```
 <label for="pretty">
    <input type="radio" value="pretty" name="quality" id="pretty"> <span>pretty</span>
  </label>

  <label for="accessible-and-pretty">
    <input type="radio" value="pretty"  name="quality" id="accessible-and-pretty" checked> <span>accessible and pretty</span>
  </label>
```

The question that I have is how can I achieve the attached image look and feel?

[image]

I am having trouble figuring our how to make the green area smaller or if there is something else I need to do to achieve that

Comment: Try googling "[radio button css](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=radio+button+css&*)".

Comment: well yeah I wouldn't say there is a way to do it with before and after if i didn't google. Not the answer I am looking for

Comment: I made updates.. check out the fiddle above.. i still need assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel free to change the colors, gradients and sizes to match your requirement.

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.radio-grp {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

input[type="radio"] + label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

input[type="radio"] + label,
.radio-txt {
  cursor: pointer;
}

label.radio-txt {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

input[type="radio"] + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  box-shadow: 4px 5px 10px 0px #ccc inset;
}

input[type="radio"] + label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  transition: background 0.1s linear;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
  background-color: #888888;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="radio-grp">
    <input type="radio" name="demo" value="1" id="radio1" checked>
    <label for="radio1"></label>
    <label for="radio1" class="radio-txt">Demo 1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-grp">
    <input type="radio" name="demo" id="radio2" value="2">
    <label for="radio2"></label>
    <label for="radio2" class="radio-txt">Demo 2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-grp">
    <input type="radio" name="demo" id="radio3" value="3">
    <label for="radio3"></label>
    <label for="radio3" class="radio-txt">Demo 3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are awesome thank you! exactly what i was looking for. Quick question. I tried to inspect the code in the debugger when  I click each of these buttons, first one stays marked as checked and the rest don't change the attribute to checked. My guess was that these buttons by default should do that. Do I need Js for this?

Comment: Try firing the debugger on their change event rather than their click and I've added checked attribute to the first input to keep it checked when the page loads, just remove it if you want all fields to be unchecked on page load.

Comment: You can use :checked selector to find the option currently checked.

Comment: Thank you I got it!

Comment: Happy to help.!

Comment: I am so sorry to bother you again but I am trying to add a span or some words next to the radio button like I used to have initially.. but your hml is a little different so I am having a hard time doing so. Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N9tBx/2169/)
ideally they should be aligned text and radio button and when i click on either radio or label or span for it to get checked.

Comment: Can I get back to you on that after some time as I dont have PC to test it out as I'm traveling.

Comment: Thanks again, I figured it all out with radio buttons. Learning new stuff every day! I was wondering if you might have a min to peek into this ticket I opened up: [ticket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004952/styling-select-to-match-specific-design)
you are good with css so maybe you'll know the answer. 
Either way.. I wish I could give you more points than I already did :)