# styling select to match specific design

Tags: css, select

I need assistance from you CSS gurus on styling this select. I am using Jquery easydropdown and have specific look in mind.  I am very close. Please check out my [code here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EWRdox)

Here is the start of my code

```
/*My Dropdown css */
.dropdown {    
  margin: 0 auto;
    width: 210px !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.dropdown li{
    color: #f08800 !important;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.dropdown li.active{
    color: white !important;
    background-color: #f08800;
}
```

The rest can be found in the codepen project I put together.

Attached is the image of what I am looking for

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: OK, so I got closer on this but I am having trouble of combining the background image and background itself. I had to remove my gradient background that I had:

`background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 24%,#f3f3f3 91%,#e9e9e9 100%); `

again, any idea how to add gradient background and keep that image border and somehow fix right border of the select?

Comment: [my code is here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJxwyy)

Comment: for whatever reason there is all white background around .carat class with position set to relative on .dropdown. Where is this white background coming from?